# Under what condition will `str(float(val)) == val` NOT hold in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

For a string `val` variable like `"1.2345"`, does `assert str(float(val)) == val` always hold?

I've already found it doesn't always hold

```
>>> str(float('1.2345'))
'1.2345'
>>> str(float('0.1231412314124124124124124124'))
'0.12314123141241241'
```

But where is the theoretical boundary? How can we reason about under what condition the equality of the left side and right side will *not* hold?

Comment: Broadly speaking, it won't hold if your string is not exactly representable as a float.  Have a look at the IEEE floating point spec document for a deeper answer.

Comment: `"0.00"` is a trivial case where it doesn't hold.

Comment: `str(float('5'))` is `5.0`.   As pointed out above, `str(float('5.00'))` is also `5.0`.  `str(float('.5'))` is `0.5`.  So there are all sorts of cases where this doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `str(float(val))` and `val` arises from the limited precision of floating-point representations in computers. Computers use binary fractions to store floating-point numbers, and not all decimal fractions can be exact binary representations, leading to small rounding errors during conversions.

In Python, a float is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 value, offering about 15 decimal digits of precision. When the number of significant digits in a decimal string exceeds this precision (e.g., `'0.1231412314124124124124124124'` with 25 significant digits), precision loss occurs when converting it to a float and back to a string.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is No, and this has nothing to do with IEEE or anything like that.  Even on an infinite precision floating point computer (if such a thing existed), you'd run into problems.

Think about it.  "5.0", "5.00", "5", "05.0", etc will all return the exact same string when you call `str(float(x))`.  Obviously for only one of these will `str(float(x))` return x.